# Teams PowerShell: Access token validation failure

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I am trying to create a team with the new Teams Powershell. Looks like everything is working, until I try to use my service account instead of my own.
The code below is working, if I replace the $credential line and use my own credentials. If I use the automation account, then I got this:

```
New-Team : Error occurred while executing 
Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Message: Access token validation failure.
```

I tried searching for this error message, but I only found Graph API samples, that happen behind the scenes of the Teams PowerShell. I also tried other scripts, like PnP, they all work fine with the same automation account. Is this a bug in the Teams API self or can I do something on my side?

```
$credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'provisioning'  
$connection = Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $credential
$t = Get-Team -DisplayName "TEST"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your service account has proper privileges to create channel.

[image]

**Reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-teams?view=graph-rest-1.0

If you reckon you have proper privileges to create teams and channels then make sure you give full scope to the service account

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Scopes "Group.ReadWrite.All"
```

Hope it will give you some idea to solve the error. Thanks